# Tapestry Futurist claiming landmarks

Tags: tapestry

The futurists make you start from space 4 on each track, and you do not gain any benefits, bonuses, or landmarks.

Let's say you advance on the *Science* track and reach *Academic Research*. This allows you to gain the benefit (and pay for the bonus), on any advancement track. Do you also gain the landmark? Given that you are already on space 4 and no one else has reached that and took the landmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been covered on BGG forum and clarified the designer [on this page](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2372118/article/34081557#34081557).  the answer was no.

Quoting the designers response.

> My apologies for any confusion my comment on the other thread caused.
> I thought that person was just asking about gaining the Futurists at
> the beginning of the game. I've revised that comment to read, "The
> initial advancement from gaining the Futurist civilization (at the
> beginning or during the game) doesn't let you gain landmarks."
>
> Joe's answer is thus correct:
>
> Academic Research allows you to "gain the benefit & pay to gain the
> bonus (if any) of your current position on any advancement track."
>
> Gaining a landmark is neither a benefit nor a bonus, so the Futurists
> could not gain the landmark in the fourth space with Academic
> Research.